# Resize tableview cell by updating table datasource dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm displaying information fetched from a server on tableview. My tableview cell view has two vertical stackviews placed horizontally in a content view. Each stackview has 6 items and depending on data I'm hiding and showing the stackview item and setting the stackview and content view height depending on content of stackview visible items. This is all working fine and the tableview is also looking good.

Now I have a feature to delete tableview rows on swipe of a tableview row. So after deleting any row and reloading tableview cells, tableview cell height is not getting set and shrinks.

Can anyone help me with how do I update tableview height after each reload? I've tried all possible solutions but none of them worked to me.

Comment: what are you returning in the height for row method?

Comment: The cell shrinks and come back to state before you add data. Right?

Comment: @AymanIbrahim   - Height that was calculated in UIatbleview cell for each row.

Comment: @trungduc - cell shrinks and not comes to original state even i'm calling layoutIfneeded

Comment: Have you implemented delegate method heightForRow:? Try implementing your logic for height inside this method

Comment: @NitishaSharma no, i mean height of cell when shrinking is equal to the height of cell `before you pass data to it`?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi - i tried it already '   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        guard let height = cellHeights[indexPath] else { return UITableViewAutomaticDimension }
        return height
        //return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } '

Comment: I mean that it shirks because some content in stack view loss. Right?

Comment: Can you please show images for a better understanding of whats happening? @NitishaSharma

Comment: Assuming that you are deleting item in the cellHeights array every time you delete a row

Comment: @trungduc - this is how it is happening                                                     Cell 1 - height 50
Cell -2 height 100
Cell -3 -height - 65

Now if I’m deleting cell -1, cell 2 moves up and even all the method that updates height is executed successfully cell-2 takes height of cell-1 i.e

Cell 2 - height 50 cell  1-deleted
Cell -3 height 100
Cell -3 -height - 65

Comment: Show me your code which is used to delete cell

Comment: @trungduc - i'm deleting data from array which is datasource of tableview and then reloads table view

Comment: No, don't do it, you should use `deleteRowWithIndexPath`. Don't use `reloadData` of `UITableView`

Comment: @trungduc - thanks friend.I did the same now and its working good.such a silly mistake it was doing :(

Comment: @trungduc - yes please :)

Comment: Add the code that you have already tried. We can't help you if we don't know where in the code is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, in your viewDidLoad set:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 // this is an estimation but try and get it close to what the actual height may be
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Then in the tableView heightForRowAt indexPath return this:

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```